# how to rotate image in php?

Tags: php, image, rotation

I have a function that generates text that fits the lower part of a circle. Because I do not know any other way that I can make the function fit the upper part of the circle so that it faces me, I want to rotate the image, write on it, rotate it back and again write on it. How can I do that without changing the name of the image?

I have tried something like this :

```
<?php
function  create_image()
{

$im = @imagecreate(140, 140)or die("Cannot Initialize new GD image stream");
$background_color = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255);

imageellipse ( $im , $cx , $cy , $size*2 , $size*2 , $black );

write($im,$cx,$cy,$size,$s,$e,$black,$text1,$font,$size,$pad);
imagerotate($im, 180,0);
write($im,$cx,$cy,$size,$s,$e,$black,$text2,$font,$size,$pad);
imagerotate($im, 180,0);

imagepng($im,"image.png");
imagedestroy($im);  

}
?>

<?php
create_image();
print "<img src=image.png?".date("U").">";
?>
```

But it doesn't work. It doesn't rotate the image.

Can you please help me?

Thanx !

Comment: Where did you get this script ???  It not complete , has error .. and you are calling unknown functions such as `write`. its obvious its just a copy and paste .. why not explain what you want in detail

Comment: @Baba I don't think that the function write is relevant for the ideea. I need to learn how to rotate the image... without changing it's name... in php

Comment: Why do you need to rotate twice ???

Comment: try http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagerotate.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure why you need to rotate twice .. but this is what your code should look like

```
function create_image($img) {
    $im = @imagecreatefrompng($img) or die("Cannot Initialize new GD image stream");
    $rotate = imagerotate($im, 180, 0);
    imagepng($rotate);
    imagedestroy($rotate);
    imagedestroy($im);
}

header('Content-Type: image/png');
$image = "a.png";
create_image($image);
```

Comment: Thanx! Well I need to rotate it twice because the write function only writes text on the lower part of the circle...

Answer (score 4):

Why dont you just take the normal image and add some css to it

**CSS**

```
.yourImage {
 -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
 -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
 filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=3);
}
```

**HTML**

```
<img class="yourImage" src="originalImage.jpg">
```

Comment: @because this is css3 and it doesn't work with all browsers and I need to rotate the image twice. and I need to do it with php...

Answer (score 2):

You can do it easily using php rotate function. Here is simple code

```
<?php 
 $image = 'test.jpg';

// The file you are rotating

//How many degrees you wish to rotate
 $degrees = 180;

// This sets the image type to .jpg but can be changed to png or gif
 header('Content-type: image/jpeg') ;

// Create the canvas
   $src = $image;
$system = explode(".", $src);

if (preg_match("/jpg|jpeg/", $system[1]))
{
    $src_img=imagecreatefromjpeg($src);
}
if (preg_match("/png/", $system[1]))
{
    $src_img = imagecreatefrompng($src);
}
if (preg_match("/gif/", $system[1]))
{
    $src_img = imagecreatefromgif($src);
}

  // Rotates the image
  $rotate = imagerotate($src_img, $degrees, 0) ;

  // Outputs a jpg image, you could change this to gif or png if needed
  if (preg_match("/png/", $system[1]))
{
    imagepng($rotate,$image); 
} 
else if (preg_match("/gif/", $system[1]))
{
    imagegif($rotate, $image);
}
else
{
    imagejpeg($rotate, $image); 
}

imagedestroy($rotate);  
imagedestroy($src_img);

   ?>
```